# Can't error count : A problem occurred configuring project ':cloud_firestore'

Tags: flutter, gradle

> I don't understand, the more I edit, the more mistakes I make. How will this be solved?
> I've tried to check the rule in firebase, it's readable. or there are others that can be disabled and enabled again

[image: 1]